# Assign Pardot Prospect more than once to trigger Lead Assignment Rules

Tags: leads, pardot, lead-assignment

We would like to store all Marketing Qualified Leads inside a Queue named "MQL Queue". This should be done to every Prospect we get through forms into Pardot. Therefore we add the action "Assign prospect to queue" -> "MQL Queue".

But after certain criteria are met we would like to "assign them via active Lead assignment rules".
We tested it and the second assignment process is not changing Lead away from "MQL Queue" towards the logic we implemented in "Lead Assignment Rules" inside Salesforce.

Any Idea how we can make this work?

Comment: The lead having or not having an owner is the trigger to these actions. Prospects assigned to a queue are considered assigned to an owner and aren't reassigned. Have not tried this but you can give it a shot: when they're in a lead queue and you want them to be reassigned, remove the owner (the queue).  If this kicks off reassignment rules, you're in luck, else you can do something [like this](https://automationchampion.com/2021/11/01/getting-started-with-salesforce-flow-part-77-running-lead-assignment-rules-from-salesforce-flow)

Comment: That is a great link you provided. We already thought about the Flow option (unfortunately not that familiar with it), therefore the input is really helping much. Do you know why the author added a waiting time of 1minute into the Step 4.2. of the ressource you provided? It does not seem to work if you do not include this waiting period or change the Flow to "Fast Field Updates"

Comment: Unclear if it's truly needed but no harm in doing so.

Comment: Yep, no way to re-assign a prospect from Pardot side, neither in automations, nor in API (to be thorough, you can reassign via APIs 3,4 and 5 but the changes are overridden by the  next sync). Flows are definitely the way to go here, as @identigral stated it.

Comment: @identigral if you write your comment as answer i will mark it as the solution and mark this question as solved. Thank you for your help. Also thank you to Francois Perret :)